# Не работает команда ls. Clear Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ls

Не работает команда ls. Вот вывод консоли:

```
bash: ls: command not found
```

Перед этим чистил кэш. Возможно проблема в этом. Прошу помочь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну а какие команды работают? Пробовали по полному пути?

Comment: А если запустить так: /bin/ls  работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего этот скрипт удалил системный файлы. Советую перепроверять то что запускаете. Систему придется переустановить.

Comment: Понял. Благодарю за ответ.